# How to send commands to Android device using Bluetooth module

Tags: applications, samsung, bluetooth

I want to add extra physical buttons to my old Samsung Galaxy Note 4 for a project that I'm doing. Essentially, I want to be able to press one of the buttons that are connected to a Bluetooth module (GPIO pins of the module), and based on that specific button that is pressed, it will tell the Note 4 to launch a program or do a specific command. Here's the [Bluetooth module](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/100/CYBLE-0130XX-00_EZ-BLE_WICED_MODULE-1375365.pdf) that I've been looking at.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Android itself can not do what you want. You need an app that connects to your Bluetooth device and performs the action based on the received Bluetooth data. I am not sure if a standard app like Tasker or similar can communicate with generic Bluetooth devices. If not you have to develop an app on your own.

Answer (score -1):

[BlueSPP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shenyaocn.android.BlueSPP) and a Bluetooth relay can do that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/249025)